# ¿Cómo generar textos aleatorios dentro de un rango y que estos no se repitan con Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Logré que se generen textos aleatorios en un rango de 1 a 15, pero estos se repiten, quisiera saber cómo hacer para que estos no se repitan hasta que ya hayan pasado todos los textos de mi lista.

Estos se mostrarán en un `TexView = edt_Questions` al presionar un botón.

```
  // Lista de textos
  final String[] ex = {
                "rapido",
                "lento",
                "limpio",
                "ordenado",
                "sucio",
                "desordenado",
                "enojado",
                "feliz",
                "triste",
                "bueno",
                "malo",
                "bonito",
                "feo",
                "hermosa",
                "guapo",

        };

    //Generar
    btn_Generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int Questions = rand.nextInt(15);

            edt_Questions.setText(ex[Questions]);

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Se puede hacer de varias formas. Unas relativas a declarar un arreglo de "palabras ya mostradas" (o indices de palabras en el arreglo ya mostradas). O la otra es directamente ir sacandolas del arreglo (o copia del arreglo).

A mi me gusta mas siempre ir sacando (vaciando) el arreglo (o copia) por que siempre queda (a mi gusto) el codigo más limpio y intuitivo.

```
static String[] ex = {"rapido", "lento", "limpio", "ordenado", "sucio", "desordenado", "enojado", "feliz", "triste", "bueno", "malo", "bonito", "feo", "hermosa", "guapo"};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int index;
    String palabra;
    while (ex.length > 0) {
        index = random.nextInt(ex.length);
        palabra = ex[index];
        System.out.println(palabra);
        // Eliminamos la palabra seleccionada del array
        String[] newArray = new String[ex.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(ex, 0, newArray, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(ex, index + 1, newArray, index, ex.length - index - 1);
        ex = newArray;
    }
}
```

Y personalmente, para mi se ve mejor si creamos una copia del array como un arrayList, aún se ve más legible el apartado de borrar el item del array.

```
static String[] ex = {"rapido", "lento", "limpio", "ordenado", "sucio", "desordenado", "enojado", "feliz", "triste", "bueno", "malo", "bonito", "feo", "hermosa", "guapo"};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> palabras = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String palabra : ex) {
            palabras.add(palabra);
        }
        Random random = new Random();
        while (!palabras.isEmpty()) {
            int index = random.nextInt(palabras.size());
            String palabra = palabras.remove(index);
            System.out.println(palabra);
        }
    }
```

PD: Yo he puesto un while, para que veas que salen todas sin repetirse, tu en vez del while pon la función click que deseas.

Un saludo!

Comment: intente implementarlo para android studio, pero solo jenera un texto seguire intentando. Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podés hacer es, dada la lista de palabras, generar una lista de números aleatorios y consultar la lista de palabras en ese orden. Esto se puede implementar de la siguiente forma:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String[] ex = {"rapido", "lento", "limpio", "ordenado", "sucio", "desordenado", "enojado", "feliz", "triste", "bueno", "malo", "bonito", "feo", "hermosa", "guapo"};
    // Lista de números del 1 al tamaño del arreglo "ex"
    var numbers = IntStream.range(1, ex.length+1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Mezclamos la lista. Puedo repetir esta operación cuantas veces se requiera
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    // Ejemplo de recorrido de la lista;
    // Recorro usando los números de la lista mezclada como subíndices
    numbers.stream().forEach(e -> System.out.println(ex[e-1]));

}
```

De esta forma logramos recorrer la lista en forma aleatoria sin que se repitan las palabras.

Comment: Ya implemente el codigo en android studio pero solo jenera un texto al momneto de apretar el boton y se cierra la aplicacion.